# Conditional formatting(Highlighting) on pivot table in python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot-table, conditional-formatting

I have a pivot table in which I would like to have a heatmap on one column and a simple colour formatting on the other column. The code for the pivot looks like this :

```
pivot_account= pd.pivot_table(data_account, values=['Accountability'], index=['Function','comment_present'],
                 aggfunc='count')
pivot_account
```

The sample dataframe looks like this :

```
 Function          comment_present  Accountability
 Services             no    
 Manufacturing        Yes                  Abc
 Digital Technology   Yes                  Abc
 Finance              no    
 Quality              Yes                  Abc 
 Manufacturing        no    
 Human Resources      no
```

I would like to add a heat map on Accountability column basis the values that are there. The range of this column is 1-500

For comment_present column I would just like to highlight all the yes that are there in green and all the no in red.
The last thing I would want to do is to sort the pivot table by Accountability column

Comment: We  need you paste a example of your dataframe and your expected output, in this way we will have an idea of you are looking for and we be able to work with the example to get a solution

Comment: @ansev: Updated the sample dataframe and removed the output.